# The TF-IDF generated by the TfidfVectorizer of sklearn is incorrect？

Tags: tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

This is my code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import pandas as pd

textRaw = [
    "good boy girl",
    "good good good",
    "good boy",
    "good girl",
    "good bad girl",
]

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(textRaw)
allWords = vectorizer.get_feature_names_out()
dense = X.todense()
XList = dense.tolist()
df = pd.DataFrame(XList, columns=allWords)
dictionary = df.T.sum(axis=1)

print(dictionary)
```

Output:

bad     0.772536

boy     1.561542

girl    1.913661

good    2.870128

However, good appears in every document in the corpus. Its idf should be 0, which means its Tf-idf should also be 0. Why is the Tf-idf value of good calculated by TfidfVectorizer the highest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [sklearn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer) (emphasis mine):

> The formula that is used to compute the tf-idf for a term t of a
> document d in a document set is tf-idf(t, d) = tf(t, d) * idf(t), and
> the idf is computed as idf(t) = log [ n / df(t) ] + 1 (if
> smooth_idf=False), where n is the total number of documents in the
> document set and df(t) is the document frequency of t; the document
> frequency is the number of documents in the document set that contain
> the term t. **The effect of adding “1” to the idf in the equation above
> is that terms with zero idf, i.e., terms that occur in all documents
> in a training set, will not be entirely ignored.** (Note that the idf
> formula above differs from the standard textbook notation that defines
> the idf as idf(t) = log [ n / (df(t) + 1) ]).

Comment: However, even if I set smooth_ Idf=False, the Tf-idf value of good is still the highest.

Comment: I don't know if there is a problem with my code?

Comment: @smalltomato from my reading of the `smooth_idf` parameter in the quote above and in the parameter description on the page a bit further down it seems that this parameter does not actually influence the `+1` at the end, i.e., that is always there for both values of the parameter. Instead, the parameter "adds one to document frequencies, as if an extra document was seen containing every term in the collection exactly once", so that changes the `df(t)` part of the equation but _not_ the `+1` at the end. However the documentation is not fully clear on this point so maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Your code seems fine, these smoothing adjustments may have a big unwanted influence when you have only five very small documents but with a real corpus they will actually make the results better.

Comment: The reason why I have doubts is that according to the logic of the above code, when I deal with a large corpus, using TfidfVectorizer will obviously give some worthless words (not stop words) a high Tf-idf value, which makes Tf-idf completely useless.

Comment: It will not be useless, the values are high now because the idf is close to the idf of the other terms in this small corpus, but with a large corpus the idf of less common words will increase a lot while the idf of common words will stay at around 1.0 with this calculation.

Comment: Your understanding is right. I later calculated the TF-IDF manually and found that it was the same as the one generated by TfidfVectorizer. At the same time, some meaningless words with high TF-IDF value should be eliminated by judging the part of speech. Thank you.